# Laravel 9, Class "Model/App/item" not found

Tags: php, laravel-9

I'm running a Laravel 9 project locally using XAMPP, it works fine, but when I deploy it on my Ubuntu server, it gives an error as Class "App/Model/Item" not found. but it is imported at the top of my Order model and is also present in the Models folder.

**Order Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Item;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

**Item Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Color;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\Services;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function Services()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Services::class);
    }

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
    public function color()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Color::class);
    }
}
```

[this is the error when the form access the Model/Order.php for storing data in backend.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guMTb.jpg)

Comment: Run `composer dump-autoload` on the deployed machine in order to rebuild class pathes.